# Magento : Not able to set posted value in the observer

Tags: magento-1.9, php, event-observer

I am trying to modify the product price when user hit the add to cart button on product view page. For this I did some jQuery and hidden fields. Once user hit the add to cart button, I receive the hidden field data in the `observer` and modify the price and it is working fine.

**PROBLEM**

Now on the product page I have created some options with the product using html and jQuery (Not default custom option) and passing their values in the hidden filled. Now I have to show those selected option in the cart page as magento default custom option works. And for this I have created the observer to create option on the fly when user hit add to cart button. It is working fine if I pass static value in the observer for the option but I want to get those hidden value in the observer those are passed from product view page as I did earlier to modify the price before. Please my code below :

**config.xml**

```
<events>
    <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        <observers>
            <san_change_price>
                <class>webroot/observer</class>
                <method>modifyPrice</method>
            </san_change_price>
        </observers>
    </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    <sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
        <observers>
            <san_after_addtocart>
                <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>webroot/observer</class>
                <method>salesQuoteAddressCollectTotalsBefore</method>
            </san_after_addtocart>
        </observers>
    </sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
    <sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
        <observers>
            <san_show_in_admin>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>webroot/observer</class>
            <method>salesConvertQuoteItemToOrderItem</method>
            </san_show_in_admin>
        </observers>
    </sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
</events>
```

**Observer.php**

```
public function modifyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $obs)
{

    $item   = $obs->getQuoteItem();

    $item   = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
    $price  = $this->_getPriceByItem($item);
    $data   = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
    // Update Price
    $price = $data['pay-amount'];
    $item->setCustomPrice($price);
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);

    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
}

protected function _getPriceByItem(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item)
{
    $price;
    return $price;
}

public function salesQuoteAddressCollectTotalsBefore($observer)
{
    $quote = $observer->getQuote();
    $quote_items = $quote->getItemsCollection();
    $data   = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
    $print_type =  $data['printing-type'];
    //echo $print_type;exit;
    //echo '<pre>';print_r($quote_items);exit;
    foreach ($quote_items as $item) {

        $additionalOptions = array(
            array(
                'code'  => '666',
                'label' => 'Printing Type',
                'value' => 'abc'            // Have to pass $print_type
            )

        );
        $item->addOption(
            array(
                 'code'  => 'additional_options',
                 'value' => serialize($additionalOptions),
            )
        );
    }
    // echo '<pre>';
    // print_r(serialize($additionalOptions));exit;
}
public function salesConvertQuoteItemToOrderItem(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $quoteItem = $observer->getItem();
    if ($additionalOptions = $quoteItem->getOptionByCode('additional_options')) {
        $orderItem = $observer->getOrderItem();
        $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
        $options['additional_options'] = unserialize($additionalOptions->getValue());
        $orderItem->setProductOptions($options);
    }
}
```

In the above `salesQuoteAddressCollectTotalsBefore()` methode I have to set value `$print_type =  $data['printing-type'];` for 
`$additionalOptions` array. but when I set `value` as `$print_type` it shows blank in the cart page however if i pass any static value like `abc` then it works fine.

Please help me to set those hidden value to the option ($additionalOptions) and those values should be visible in the **Admin Panel** under the respective **Order Information** section **like default custom option works**

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($print_type)` ? What does it yield? I'm sure it's an array and you're trying to do an array to string conversion.

Comment: Thank You @JulienLachal! Its an array. I already try this. And I already modify the price successfully but in the observer not able to set this value dynamically. Any Idea?

Comment: array(12) {
  ["uenc"]=>
  string(80) "aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9tYWdlbnRvL21hZ2UzL2luZGV4LnBocC90ZXN0LXByb2R1Y3QuaHRtbA,,"
  ["product"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["form_key"]=>
  string(16) "E8Tw1VEHK60ruMRV"
  ["related_product"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["s"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["m"]=>
  string(2) "12"
  ["l"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["xl"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["2xl"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["3xl"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["pay-amount"]=>
  string(3) "154"
  ["printing-type"]=>
  string(16) "Clothing Pricing"
}

Comment: What do you get if you pass the dynamic `$printing_type` and then `var_dump(serialize($additionalOptions))`?

Comment: Value is showing here. But in the cart page, only label display and value field  is empty :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the event `sales_quote_collect_totals_before` is dispatched in more places than you think.
Not sure about it, but I think it is dispatched when you add a product to the cart and when the cart page is reloaded. You can easily test this by adding a logger in your observer and see how many times it is executed.
Add this in your observer:

```
Mage::log('running my observer', null, 'sales.txt', true);
```

then add a product to the cart and see how many logs there are in the file `var/log/sales.txt`.
What I presume is that the first time the observer runs, your value gets added to the quote item, but the second time (when the cart page is loaded) that value is reset to null because there is no print-type in the request.
this explains why it works with a hard-coded value, because the second time the observer fires, you still get the same value attached to the quote item.

As a general rule, it is dangerous to use the request in any observer that is not dispatched from a controller.
You can try to set the value like this :

```
$data   = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
$print_type = isset($data['printing-type']) ? $data['printing-type'] : null;
if (!is_null($print_type))  {
    //your foreach loop here
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Marius Sir, for well Explanation! It is working as expected. All the options values are available in the admin panel under respective `order information` as well. Thank you :)

Comment: Please check for typo above `$data   = Mage::app()()->getRequest()->getParams();`

Comment: Sorry for that. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

First thing for post value

`Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams()` will not work you have to use

`Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost()`

Comment: Thank You @Murtuza ! But I have tried with both. Same issue

Comment: is there any place where you get this post data ?

Comment: if yes save it in registry and after use clear data form registry

Comment: inside `salesQuoteAddressCollectTotalsBefore()` here i have to set value to array

Comment: Have you tried this `
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParams();`

Comment: Not getting the point **save it in registry**

Comment: @SanchitGupta give me 10 min I will explain it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49645/discussion-between-sanchit-gupta-and-murtuza-zabuawala).

Comment: @SanchitGupta please provide full class code

Comment: Thank you @Murtuza Zabuawala! To coming back. Above is full Observer class code.

Comment: Thank you !  @Murtuza Zabuawala for your help. Issue has been fixed now :)

Comment: @SanchitGupta Ok what was the issue?

Comment: Don't know clearly but posted values was reset from somewhere. I will share my code file with you :)

Comment: @SanchitGupta,  Ok share and allocate your bounty to someone as you cannot get reimbursement of those points

Answer (score 1):

```
public function modifyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $obs)
{
    $data   = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
    if (isset($data['pay-amount']) && $data['pay-amount'] != '') {
            //do your changes here...
    }
}
```

You can try with below for custom option,

```
$additionalOptions = array(
            array(
                'label' => 'Printing Type',
                'value' => $print_type            // Have to pass $print_type
            )

        );
        $item->addOption(
            array(
                 'code'  => 'additional_options',
                 'value' => serialize($additionalOptions),
            )
        );
```

check with above code.

Comment: Thankyou @Rakesh! But I need to get posted values in `salesQuoteAddressCollectTotalsBefore()` and then set the value to custom option.  You can see the discussion with @Murtuza Zabuawala

Comment: are you want to get value inside salesQuoteAddressCollectTotalsBefore()?

Comment: I am able to get all posted values but when I set any posted value in `$additionalOptions`  (Where I set `abc` above). then it is showing empty in the cart page But if i set `abc` or any static value then it work fine.

Comment: means dynamically value are not set in your above code, right?

Comment: You are Right !

Comment: $print_type value is print in above ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49967/discussion-between-sanchit-gupta-and-rakesh).

Comment: Have you try with above code mention?

Comment: Yes! Still working on it.... But no success

Comment: Thank you !  @Rakesh for your help. Issue has been fixed now :)

Comment: Nice, You can share your code if your code is differ from above. Thanks.

Comment: Sure I will update this soon